# how to click in this element by xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an HTML code like this and need to click in the button

```
<div aria-label="إجراءات إضافية" class="oajrlxb2 g5ia77u1 qu0x051f esr5mh6w e9989ue4 r7d6kgcz rq0escxv nhd2j8a9 pq6dq46d p7hjln8o kvgmc6g5 cxmmr5t8 oygrvhab hcukyx3x jb3vyjys rz4wbd8a qt6c0cv9 a8nywdso i1ao9s8h esuyzwwr f1sip0of lzcic4wl n00je7tq arfg74bv qs9ysxi8 k77z8yql l9j0dhe7 abiwlrkh p8dawk7l cbu4d94t taijpn5t k4urcfbm" role="button" tabindex="0">
```

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and ["How much research effort is expected?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

According to @Jhon tech, The unique and working locator is  `div[aria-label='إجراءات إضافية']`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[aria-label='إجراءات إضافية']").click()
```

Comment: This is very likely not going to work if there is more than one button on the page. A more specific locator is advised and probably required.

Comment: As there is no real  url here , so  I can't check whether it's unique or not.

Comment: True but because of that, it's not a good assumption that there is only one button. At least a mention of "This will only work if there is only one button on the page" and an alternative locator would be more likely useful to OP and future readers.

Comment: You could instead use `div[aria-label='إجراءات إضافية']` and if that's not specific enough, maybe throw in the `role='button']` portion.

Comment: Alright but I'm waiting to get feedback but no response

Comment: The question is closed now so you won't likely get one.

Comment: div[aria-label='إجراءات إضافية']  its worked